# Method to update list view called from broadcast receiver does not work

Tags: android, android-listview, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I encountered a problem when implementing broadcast receiver.

I have this function inside Fragment class:

```
public void reloadMessages() {
    List<SmsList> values = smsToSmsList(getAllSms());
    mPostAdapter.clear();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        mPostAdapter.addAll(values);
    } else {
        for (SmsList smsList : values) {
            mPostAdapter.add(smsList);
        }
    }
    mPostAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(null, "reloadMessages");
}
```

and I call it from broadcast receiver:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                mainFragment.reloadMessages();

        Log.d("myactivity", "broadcast received");
    }
};
```

Analyzing with debugger shows that this function is called properly, but nothing happens. 
I performed a test and called that function from onclick function and it works properly.

What is the problem?

I tried using runOnUiThread() and using Handler but nothing changes.

Answer (score -1):

Before API level 11, you could not perform any asynchronous operation in the onReceive() method, because once the onReceive() method had been finished, the Android system was allowed to recycle that component. If you have potentially long running operations, you should trigger a service instead.

Since Android API 11 you can call the goAsync() method. This method returns an object of the PendingResult type. The Android system considers the receiver as alive until you call the PendingResult.finish() on this object. With this option you can trigger asynchronous processing in a receiver.

What you need to do instead is to start a service which will perform such operation whenever the event is broadcast:

```
new BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomService.class);
    context.startService(intent);
  }
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

You may be missing something about the matter, such as correctly declaring xml components and permissions regarding broadcast receiving and services.

I highly recommend you follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) tutorial through as it will make you understand how do these work.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I created the service, but how can I access fragment, MainActivity or at least listview inside it?

Comment: @infinity_pie It works the other way around. You communicate from the Activity into the Service. [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) is a good tutorial from the official android developer's site which will help you understand and implement this very thing.

Comment: unfortunately starting service does not solve the problem. I created an inner class which extends Service and started it from receiver, nothing happens despite the updating UI function being executed. When I again start this service with onClick method, everything is ok.

Comment: @infinity_pie Is the receiver being called? If you cannot get a Log.i() output from onReceive() then the problem lies elsewhere. However using Service is still the best approach for dealing with running broadcast processes. Editing with possible missing parts.

Comment: I tried to debug with first version (where i call updatingUI method directly from onReceive) and with break point set before executing the updatingUI method and let app go, everything works...